# speech_recognition in python not working error

Tags: python

I keep receiving this error:

```
C:\Users\5570>C:\Users\5570\Desktop\S.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\5570\Desktop\S.py", line 1, in <module>
    import speech_recognition as sr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

Comment: pip install SpeechRecognition install it first then close open idle and open again  and show how you are importing that module

Comment: install it in the right enviornment and make sure to open it in the installed enviorment

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

Windows:

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

Linux:

```
sudo pip3 install SpeechRecognition
```

Comment: I have it installed, but it still says the same

Comment: Never run `sudo pip`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it in the same *environment* where you want to use it. I suggest creating a proper project structure with Poetry.

First, install [Poetry](https://poetry.eustace.io).

Then create the project with

```
poetry new --src myproject
```

It will create a directory called `myproject/`. Enter it.

Install the dependency with

```
poetry add SpeechRecognition
```

Inside `myproject/src/myproject/app.py` put

```
import speechrecognition
```

Try running it with

```
poetry run python -m myproject.app
```

If there's no error, it worked.